# Take next item from list while iterating with another list

Tags: c#

I have two list

```
List<string> listA;
List<string> listB;
```

How to get next item of listA when im iterating with listB? Pseudocode:

```
List<dynamic> listC = new List<dynamic>();
foreach (var elementA in listA)
{
   listC.Add(new
   { 
        a: elementA,
        b: listB.TakeNextItem() // how to achive this?
   });
}
```

Comment: You could use a for loop and then take it with the index. That can lead to problems tough if listB is smaller than listA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip):

```
var listC = listA
    .Zip(listB, (a, b) => new { a, b })
    .ToList();
```

This iterates over both lists and projects items into a new list.

It also statically types your `listC` variable, rather than using `dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a for loop instead of a foreach loop and then use the current index to access both `listA` and `listB` at the same time.

```cs
List<dynamic> listC = new List<dynamic>();

// When listA Count is as bigger as listB don't execute for-loop
if (listA.Count > listB.Count) {
    return;
}

for (int i = 0; i < listA.Count; i++) {
   listC.Add(new { 
        a = listA[i],
        b = listB[i]
   });
}
```